# How do I find a user by their `display_name`?

Tags: support, api-v2, documentation, ruby

I am using Serel (the Ruby wrapper) and would like to be able to find a user by their `display_name`.

As it stands right now, I can only find them via an ID - like `Serel::User.find(1,2,3)`.

I tried doing this:

```
Serel::User.filter("marcamillion").get
[INFO][2013-04-13 18:33:03] Making request to /2.0/users?filter=marcamillion&site=stackoverflow&key=2some_key
 => []
```

But that doesn't work.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `inname` parameter of [the users path](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users).  For example [this gets users with `marcamillion` in their name, on Stack Overflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users#order=desc&sort=reputation&inname=marcamillion&filter=!-.mgWLMJhy5E&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

Note that the `filter` parameter controls what *fields* are returned, not the *content* of those fields.

I don't use Serel (or much Ruby), but the syntax is *probably*:

```
Serel::User.inname('marcamillion').get
```

Or, with some more useful fields returned:

```
Serel::User.inname('marcamillion').filter('!-.mgWLMJhy5E').get
```